# Make an analog pulse generator

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I'm working on a project that requires an pulse voltage with a frequency of 50 Hz and a duty cycle of 5 to 10%. How can I make that with analog circuits? I've a DC voltage input from 0 to 5 volts and the output has to give a pulse that varies between 1ms and 2ms

My work:

I've made a Relaxation Oscillator, to get the sawtooth voltage across the capacitor. But how do I proceed?

[image: Here you see what I mean]

Comment: Use an LTC6992.

Comment: The problem is that I haven't the required voltage that we have to put into the MOD-pin

Comment: Have you ever heard of a potential divider?

Comment: Show us a schematic of what you've got so far. We can't guess. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Yes, I've Any aka but how can I use it. And transistor I said that I've a Relaxation Oscillator that's the thing I got so far

Comment: @JeansBoss: OK. I tried to help ...

Comment: @JeansBoss - Click on Edit to alter your post. Then either click on the button that has a diode symbol as part of its icon (7th from the left) or hit ctrl-m.

Comment: See my edit, maybe this makes a lot clear

Comment: @JeansBoss - No, that does not make it clear. Please provide a schematic of what you have so far. What, exactly, is your "relaxation oscillator"? No explanation, please, just a schematic.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: I suspect that his relaxation oscillator may be irrelevant. He's just looking for a "voltage-controlled PWM generator, input 0 - 5 V, output 5 to 10%, with 20 ms period".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're up to it, I'd recommend looking into something called a monostable vibrator (it's really just a one shot pulser, each time you trigger it, it generates a single pulse - you can chose how long the pulse is). Monostables can be built using 555 timer chips and there's about a billion 555 example circuits on the internet for doing just about everything, ideally find something by Forrest Mims, bit of a 555 guru.